# How do I replace an array element in LabView? (2d array of pictures)

Tags: arrays, image, element, labview

so I have a final project for a class where I need to make a video game in LabView. The issue I'm having at the moment is that I can't figure out the 'right' way to put 'yourShip.png' into the 2d array of 2d pictures at [0,0]. Every tutorial I can find basically has exactly what I have down below in the screenshot, and it makes sense to me. However, running the program quickly shows that it does nothing.

To describe the code, I have a path constant that leads to the picture, which feeds to a draw flattened pixelmap function. Up to this point I know the code works, since creating a test indicator reveals as such. However, next I try to use the replace array subset function to replace the (default blank) 2d picture at [0,0] with yourShip.png. 'screen' is a 5x5 2d array of 2d pictures. The local variable of the same name being outputted to is indeed the very same array.

My main guess with why my code doesn't work is because of the way I'm taking screen as the input variable and then outputting to it via a local variable. However, if this is wrong, I'm confused with how I should do it. All I want to do is 'spawn' the image at the correct index.

[image: Current code, supposed to replace 2d picture [0,0] with yourShip.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *replace array subset* works quite literally, i.e. it can only replace *existing* elements.
If there is no element at the specified index because the array is smaller, the function will do just nothing.

I guess your array is empty, so, initialize your screen array first to a size of at least 1x1.